# Wamp Server Offline error

Tags: wamp

Some of you might get the “Server Offline” error after you install WAMP on your windows 7 system. This happens if IIS server was installed in the system prior to the installation of WAMP thus creating the clash of the port address where both the servers are trying to access

Answer (score 5):

first of all if you are using SKYPE try to change the port by opening Skype, then:

- Tools menu
- Options
- Advanced Options
- Connections
- Then uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 ......"
- save
- restart Skype

second if the problem still exists try to find if you are using - or was using - other Apache server (for example XAMPP server), if so try to remove it
and after removing it, go to regedit by:

- press on keyboard the "windows" button + "r" button, this will open the Run command
- type "regedit" (without "")
- open Edit menu then Find  (you can press "CTRL" button + "F" button)
- search for anything belongs to the other apache server and delete it (You should be careful while you are doing this step)

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you found the answer, but my issue was skype was running. It runs on port 80 i guess. Closing it solved my problem.